# How to break in gdb based on array contents?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am trying to place a conditional breakpoint on a function that would check the contents of an array. My idea was to use `memcmp()` in the condition:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t arr[4];
} arg_t;
```

Then in gdb (declaring an array inline):

```
b func() if memcmp(arg.arr, (uint8_t[]){1, 2, 3, 4}, sizeof(arg.arr)) == 0
```

However, this does not work:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Too many array elements
```

I can do it with `if arg.arr[0] == 1 && arg.arr[1] == 2 && ...` but in my real case access to the array (containing an IPv6 address) is rather convoluted, so it becomes unwieldy rather quickly.

**UPDATE:** After Mark's comment, I tried the following test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  uint8_t a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  printf("memcmp returns %d\n", memcmp(a, (uint8_t[4]){1,2,3,4}, sizeof(a)));
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling it, I placed a conditional break on the return using the explicit array size syntax, and it worked but it does not seem to stop as expected:

```
(gdb) br hello.c:8 if memcmp(a, (uint8_t[4]){1,2,3,4}, sizeof(a)) == 0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x75c: file hello.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /mnt/c/stuff/src/test/hello
memcmp returns 0
[Inferior 1 (process 153) exited normally]
```

I was trying to evaluate the return value of the function at the break site manually:

```
(gdb) br hello.c:8
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x800075c.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x800075c: file hello.c, line 8.
(gdb) dele 1
(gdb) run
Starting program: /mnt/c/stuff/src/test/hello
memcmp returns 0

Breakpoint 2, main () at hello.c:8
8       return 0;
(gdb) p  memcmp(a, (uint8_t[4]){1,2,3,4}, sizeof(a))
$1 = (int (*)(const void *, const void *, size_t)) 0x7fffff18aba0 <__memcmp_avx2_movbe>
```

I was surprised to see this, I suspect this may be due to memcmp() being a compiler intrinsic to the avx2 instruction, in which case I might need to cast it somehow?

Comment: gdb will accept `(uint8_t[4]){1, 2, 3, 4}`

Comment: I don't know why gdb isn't invoking `memcmp` correctly, but if you have a not-too-old gdb, there should be a `$_memeq` convenience function that's like memcmp except it returns 1 if the args are equal. Can you try `b func() if $_memeq(arg.arr, (uint8_t[4]){1, 2, 3, 4}, sizeof(arg.arr))`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That works great, thanks! Care to make it an answer so I can accept?

Comment: OK. I'd like to explain *why* (uint8_t[]) and memcpy don't work as expected. A day or two OK?

Comment: The question was about making a conditional break with memory comparison which your comment answered, and I'm totally fine with $_memeq() being the answer, but I respect that you are being thorough (I'm curious about the answer as well), so sure, I'll wait. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Posting my own answer to be able to close this, but credit goes to @mark-plotnick)

It works with the gdb builtin `$_memeq` instead of using `memcmp` - suspecting because of the latter not being a real function in my environment but YMMV:

```
(gdb) br arrbreak.c:8 if $_memeq(a, (uint8_t[4]){1,2,3,4}, sizeof(a))
Breakpoint 2 at 0x800075c: file arrbreak.c, line 8.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /mnt/c/stuff/src/test/arrbreak
memcmp returns 0

Breakpoint 2, main () at arrbreak.c:8
8         return 0;
(gdb) p $_memeq(a, (uint8_t[4]){1,2,3,4}, sizeof(a))
$1 = 1
(gdb) p $_memeq(a, (uint8_t[4]){1,2,3,5}, sizeof(a))
$2 = 0
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want, but for complex tests, I get the program to help `gdb` by adding some check routines.

---

Method 1:

I create a `void checkon (void) { if (expr_to_stop_on) badnews(); }`

And then have: `void badnews { stopme = 1; }`

I then instrument the code with calls to `checkon`

I then tell `gdb` to do `b badnews`.

---

Method 2:

An alternative may be to create: `int checkfail(void) { return expr_to_stop_on; }`

Then, tell `gdb` to `watch myarray`.

This creates a watchpoint (using H/W assist). The watchpoint is like a breakpoint.

You can then do: `cond 1 checkfail()`

---

Method 3:

Similar to method 2, but instead of a watchpoint, use a tracepoint [with the same `cond` command (Actually, you may need to use `actions` instead).

This essentially single steps the program and allows a set of commands to be executed at every tracepoint.

This can be *slow* because every line has to do these things.

I think method 2 is probably the best bet.